# Cookie empty javascript NodeJS

Tags: jquery, node.js, cookies

I am using nodeJS and MQTT and created a https server

I am trying to depict several pictures on my website according to whom is logged in by using JQuery.

In order to know which pictures should be shown, I´d like to store the username in a cookie.
However, whenever I use

```
 document.cookie = document.getElementById("user").value
```

and I try to make an output via console.log(document.cookie) on another page I just receive an empty string.

I´ve almost tried everything but simply cannot get it working...

Did anybody have the same problem and found a solution?

Comment: Are you trying to add the cookie in NodeJS or in the browser?

Comment: I try to add it in the browser

Comment: Acutally, I am just using JQuery in order to show or hide the pictures. I use JavaScript to set the cookie